# Convenient custom key bindings for accented chars

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, customization, key-bindings, diacritics

My new machine has a US English keyboard layout. I write a lot in Spanish and French. I miss the accent keys of Latin keyboards.

I have customized key bindings using the right Alt key to type those characters. So (<kbd>rightAlt</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>) types á,  (<kbd>rightAlt</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>) types ñ, and so forth. I find them pretty hard to use.

Ideally, custom key bindings should not conflict with built-in/common bindings from either the system of other apps. (Hence my choice of right-alt. I run Ubuntu Linux, by the way.)

I wonder what other key bindings forum members use for this purpose. Any general advise on this matter will be most welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A late answer for people looking into this issue :

I don't have anything to recommend for Spanish accents but for French accents with qwerty I use something that deserved to be spread: it's an old config called `French Qwerty` that has installation utilities for Ubuntu / ArchLinux / Mac OS / Windows and feels very intuitive.

You can see how to install and use it on : http://marin.jb.free.fr/qwerty-fr/

Answer (score 0):

OK. After weeks of on-and-off investigation by trial-and-error, I found an easy solution that, if not ideal, is quite flexible.

I simply chose an additional input method: *English (US, international with dead keys)*.

In Ubuntu, go to Settings>Keyboard>Text entry and select add (or +). Choose 'English (US, international with dead keys)'.

Thus, to get á, you type `'a` rather than `rightAlt+'a`.

I did not remove the original input method---mine was English (US). This way, I can toggle one or the other: dead keys when writing text, standard when writing code (else you lose easy access to characters such as ` or ').